# Nativescript angular worker updated example?

Tags: angular, multithreading, nativescript, worker, nativescript-angular

Is there any updated example for `nativescript worker` for angular? because when I checked this repo `https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader` and copy their angular demo and run it I got an error, and leading me to this issue https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader/issues/23 which leads to another pull request https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader/pull/39.

Comment: I am sure you must have checked but just fyi https://stackoverflow.com/a/54546214/4982126

Comment: I can't get past this https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader/issues/23 error. :(

Comment: The ts-compiler may able to compile the TS dependencies into JS and use it in worker, so you may try importing the TS files with JS extension. Something like `import * as example from '~/path/to/tsfile.js';`.